# Impossible to run my Apple Watch application in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode6, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to run an Apple WatchKit target with my Universal app, using Xcode 6.2

I'm probably doing something wrong, but I can't access to the simulator in the scheme menu

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: try changing it from universal to iPhone and then change back to universal from target's General tab

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed.

Comment: My "solution" was to back up my Watch app files, delete Watch app target & WatchKit extension, then create a new Watch target and import my code and storyboard. Now it works as expected !

Answer (score 16):

Have you tried to attach it in the iOS simulator?

[image: Attach in Hardware/External Displays/Apple Watch]

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a bug that at times affects some Build Schemes for some reason. Fortunately, it is easy to fix.

- In the menu that appears in your screenshot, select "New Scheme".
- Select your WatchKit App as the target, and give it a name. Click 'OK'.
- In the new entry in the Schemes menu, you should now be able to open your WatchKit app in the simulator.

You can also correct this issue via "Manage Schemes" and removing and re-adding your existing WatchKit App.

Answer (score 2):

### No luck?

For those who are still having a headache after doing this list of things:

1. Creating new schemes
2. Hacking Targeted Device Family
3. Autocreating schemes
4. Clearing Derived Data and Module Cache cleaning Project
5. Restarting Xcode, Mac

### History

It took me about 3 hours to get rid of no targets (my case was My Mac target), I copied the project somewhere to keep my current data and I did these things to inspect:

1. Deleting current targets (**AppExtension** and **WatchKit**)
2. Creating them again (for my surprise the iOS Simulator this time came up)
3. Opening **Product**->**Scheme**->**Edit Scheme**
4. Selecting a scheme which target is **WatchKit App**
5. Under Build I see that my old scheme had only its own target (WatchKit one) while the new that was generated from new targets had 3 targets (MainApp, WatchKit and WatchExtension)
6. I did the same thing to my old ones by adding target, and the simulator came  up, ran it and worked perfectly

## Solution

1. Open **Product**->**Scheme**->**Edit Scheme**
2. Select your ***WatchKit Scheme***
3. Select **Build** and if you see only one target, that could be the case, add the other required target (in my case were MainApp and WatchKit Extension)
4. If it works, cheers :)

Hope it helps somebody

Answer (score 1):

This is likely the issue reported in the [Xcode Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html) whereby Xcode can't communicate with the simulator service if you rename Xcode.app.  Please reboot your system.

> Renaming Xcode.app after running any of the Xcode tools in that bundle
>   may cause iOS Simulator to be no longer be available. Either rename
>   Xcode.app back to what it was when first launched or restart your Mac.
>   (16646772)

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Watch Kit project in lower versions of Xcode (6.1 and below)  you wont get the simulator options.

Not sure if you have done the same, but I just observed this today.